# error while compile driver

Tags: wireless, drivers, kernel, compiling, broadcom

when i want compile broadcom wireless driver it give this error :

```
root@hello-notebook:/home/hello/bcm/broadcom# make
KBUILD_NOPEDANTIC=1 make -C /lib/modules/`uname -r`/build M=`pwd`
make[1]: Entering directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-3.16.0-23-generic'
CFG80211 API is prefered for this kernel version
Using CFG80211 API
  CC [M]  /home/hello/bcm/broadcom/src/wl/sys/wl_linux.o
/home/hello/bcm/broadcom/src/wl/sys/wl_linux.c: In function ‘wl_dump_ver’:
/home/hello/bcm/broadcom/src/wl/sys/wl_linux.c:2041:3: error: macro "__DATE__" might prevent reproducible builds [-Werror=date-time]
   __DATE__, __TIME__, EPI_VERSION_STR);
   ^
/home/hello/bcm/broadcom/src/wl/sys/wl_linux.c:2041:13: error: macro "__TIME__" might prevent reproducible builds [-Werror=date-time]
   __DATE__, __TIME__, EPI_VERSION_STR);
             ^
cc1: some warnings being treated as errors
scripts/Makefile.build:257: recipe for target '/home/hello/bcm/broadcom/src/wl/sys/wl_linux.o' failed
make[2]: *** [/home/hello/bcm/broadcom/src/wl/sys/wl_linux.o] Error 1
Makefile:1345: recipe for target '_module_/home/hello/bcm/broadcom' failed
make[1]: *** [_module_/home/hello/bcm/broadcom] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-3.16.0-23-generic'
Makefile:136: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

please help me

the driver file name is hybrid-v35-nodebug-pcoem-6_30_223_141.tar.gz

forgive me aboat my english

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not need to compile this driver from source this way. This driver is already in Ubuntu repositories. It can be installed by running

```
sudo apt-get install bcmwl-kernel-source
```

Comment: i want to compile it with monitoring mode enabe

Comment: this file is a deb file not source .

Comment: when i extract deb file and compile the file manually this error still here

Comment: i want to compile it to enableing monitor mode on broadcom bcm43142

Comment: Monitoring mode is not available with this chip on Linux.